# Modificar valor variable en script al hacer click sobre un label

Tags: javascript

Buenas,

Estoy trabajando con un pequeño script que se ejecuta al hacer click sobre un `label`. Al hacerlo activa o desactiva un input de tipo checkbox, y en función de esto quiero que muestre una cosa u otra en pantalla (si se ha suscrito o no).

Los parámetros los paso por AJAX para que no se me recargue la página, pero me encuentro con que la variable en JS no se actualiza, tiene siempre el mismo valor, lo curioso es que la base de datos la actualiza bien

```
$agregar = $usuario;
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE ID = :id");
$statement->execute(array(":id" => $hilo_asunto[0]['ID']));
$resultado_me_gusta = $statement->fetchAll();

$porciones = explode(";", $resultado_me_gusta[0]['suscritos']);

$contador = 0;

foreach ($porciones as $porcion) {
   if ($porcion ==  $agregar) {
      $contador++;
   }
}

if ($usuario != "null") {
   if ($contador == 0) {
      echo "<form class='' name='suscribe' id='suscribirse_" . $id . "' title='Suscripcion post' action='foro.php?foro=" . $foro ."&subforo=" . $subforo . "&hilo=Vamos%dale&ID=" . $id . "' method='post'>";
          echo "<input class='suscribe_box' type='checkbox' id='suscribe_" . $id . "' name='subs' checked>";
          echo "<label id='suscripcion_" . $id . "'  class='suscribirse' onclick='myFunction_suscribirse($id)' for='suscribirse_" . $id . "'>Suscribirse</label>";
          echo "<label id='suscripcion_oculto_" . $id . "'  class='label_oculto' onclick='myFunction_suscribirse($id)' for='suscribirse_" . $id . "'>Ya suscrito</label>";
   } else {
          echo "<form class='' name='suscribe' id='suscribirse_" . $id . "' title='Suscripcion post' action='foro.php?foro=" . $foro ."&subforo=" . $subforo . "&hilo=Vamos%dale&ID=" . $id . "' method='post'>";
          echo "<input class='suscribe_box' type='checkbox' id='suscribe_" . $id . "' name='subs' checked>";
          echo "<label id='suscripcion_" . $id . "'  class='label_oculto' onclick='myFunction_suscribirse($id)' for='suscribirse_" . $id . "'>Suscribirse</label>";
          echo "<label id='suscripcion_oculto_" . $id . "'  class='suscribirse' onclick='myFunction_suscribirse($id)' for='suscribirse_" . $id . "'>Ya suscrito</label>";
   }

   echo "</form>";

}
```

El script que se ejecuta:

```
<script>
        function myFunction_suscribirse(respuesta_id) {
            let suscribirse;
            var id_respuesta = respuesta_id;
               var d = document.getElementById("suscripcion_"+id_respuesta);
               var form = document.getElementById("suscribirse_"+id_respuesta);
               var respuesta_id = "respuesta_" + respuesta_id;

              if( $("#suscribe_"+id_respuesta).prop('checked') ) {
                  suscribirse = 1;
                  d.style.background = "transparent";
                  d.style.color = "#949494";
              } else {
                  suscribirse = 0;
                  form.style.background = "transparent";
              }

              console.log(suscribirse)

               $.ajax ({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'proces_suscribe.php',
                 data: { "corazon": suscribirse, "id_respuesta":id_respuesta }
               });



          };
        </script>
```

En este punto la variable `suscribirse` tiene siempre el valor 1, cuando debería variar entre 0 y 1 en función de si se activa o no el input de tipo checkbox.

El fichero proces_suscribe.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'admin/config.php';

try {
    $conexion = new PDO($bd_config['dbname'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['password'] );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}


$heart = isset($_POST['suscribirse'])? $_POST['suscribirse'] : 0;
$like_id = isset($_POST['id_respuesta'])? $_POST['id_respuesta'] : 0;

if ($conexion) {

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE ID = :id");
    $statement->execute(array(":id" => $like_id));
    $resultado_me_gusta = $statement->fetchAll();

    $agregar = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    $todos_suscritos = $resultado_me_gusta[0]['suscritos'];

    $porciones = explode(";", $resultado_me_gusta[0]['suscritos']);

    $contador = 0;

    foreach ($porciones as $porcion) {
        if ($porcion ==  $agregar) {
            $contador++;
        }
    }

    //SI CONTADOR ES DISTINTO A 0 SIGNIFICA QUE YA HA DADO ME GUSTA, CON LO QUE HRBÍA QUE QUITARLO DE LA BAES DE DATOS PORQUE YA NO LE GUSTA

    if ($contador == 0) {
        $todos_suscritos .= $agregar . ";";

        $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE comentarios SET suscritos = :agregar WHERE id = $like_id");
        $statement->execute(array(":agregar" => $todos_suscritos));

        //hay que quitarle uno porque siempre cuenta un array vacío...

        echo "<p>Ya estás suscrito</p>";



    } else {

        $a_borrar = $agregar . ";";
        $todos_suscritos = str_replace("$a_borrar","", $todos_suscritos);

        $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE comentarios SET suscritos = :agregar WHERE id = $like_id");
        $statement->execute(array(":agregar" => $todos_suscritos));


        //hay que quitarle uno porque siempre cuenta un array vacío...

        echo "<p class='suscribirse'>Suscribirse</p>";


    }

}

?>
```

Al no conseguir que la variable del script se modifique correctamente no puedo hacer que se recargue la página con el contenido correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código PHP que compartes (o mejor dicho el HTML que genera) tiene un problema: los `label` están apuntando al ID del formulario (`'suscribirse_" . $id . "'`), cuando deberían estar apuntando al del checkbox (`'suscribe_" . $id . "'`). Como apunta al ID equivocado, la caja del checkbox siempre estará marcada (me imagino que la tienes oculta de alguna manera y por eso no la ves) y el valor de la variable `suscribirse` siempre será 1.

Éste es tu código generado sin ninguna modificación, sólo asumiendo que el valor de `$i` será 1:

```js
function myFunction_suscribirse(respuesta_id) {
  let suscribirse;
  var id_respuesta = respuesta_id;
  var d = document.getElementById("suscripcion_"+id_respuesta);
  var form = document.getElementById("suscribirse_"+id_respuesta);
  var respuesta_id = "respuesta_" + respuesta_id;

  if( $("#suscribe_"+id_respuesta).prop('checked') ) {
    suscribirse = 1;
    d.style.background = "transparent";
    d.style.color = "#949494";
  } else {
    suscribirse = 0;
    form.style.background = "transparent";
  }

  console.log(suscribirse)

  $.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'proces_suscribe.php',
    data: { "corazon": suscribirse, "id_respuesta":id_respuesta }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class='' name='suscribe' id='suscribirse_1' title='Suscripcion post' action='foro.php?foro=test&subforo=test&hilo=Vamos%dale&ID=1' method='post'>
  <input class='suscribe_box' type='checkbox' id='suscribe_1' name='subs' checked>
  <label id='suscripcion_1'  class='suscribirse' onclick='myFunction_suscribirse(1)' for='suscribirse_1'>Suscribirse</label>
  <label id='suscripcion_oculto_1'  class='label_oculto' onclick='myFunction_suscribirse(1)' for='suscribirse_1'>Ya suscrito</label>
</form>
```

Como puedes ver, los `label` apuntan al formulario (el ID del formulario está en el `for` de los `label`), por lo que el valor del checkbox nunca se actualiza y siempre será 1 (porque está marcado por defecto).

Si haces que los `label` apunten al checkbox en su lugar, el checkbox se marcará/desmarcará correctamente, y el valor de la variable `suscribirse` cambiará de 1 a 0 respectivamente:

```js
function myFunction_suscribirse(respuesta_id) {
  let suscribirse;
  var id_respuesta = respuesta_id;
  var d = document.getElementById("suscripcion_"+id_respuesta);
  var form = document.getElementById("suscribirse_"+id_respuesta);
  var respuesta_id = "respuesta_" + respuesta_id;

  if( $("#suscribe_"+id_respuesta).prop('checked') ) {
    suscribirse = 1;
    d.style.background = "transparent";
    d.style.color = "#949494";
  } else {
    suscribirse = 0;
    form.style.background = "transparent";
  }

  console.log(suscribirse)

  $.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'proces_suscribe.php',
    data: { "corazon": suscribirse, "id_respuesta":id_respuesta }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class='' name='suscribe' id='suscribirse_1' title='Suscripcion post' action='foro.php?foro=test&subforo=test&hilo=Vamos%dale&ID=1' method='post'>
  <input class='suscribe_box' type='checkbox' id='suscribe_1' name='subs' checked>
  <label id='suscripcion_1'  class='suscribirse' onclick='myFunction_suscribirse(1)' for='suscribe_1'>Suscribirse</label>
  <label id='suscripcion_oculto_1'  class='label_oculto' onclick='myFunction_suscribirse(1)' for='suscribe_1'>Ya suscrito</label>
</form>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Vaya fallo...no sé cómo se me ha podido pasar.